# RVM / downgrading bundler gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I have the following interesting scenario:

I've install ruby 1.9.2 via RVM and it came prepackaged with bundler 1.1.4.

My application requires bundler 1.0.15.

I've tried running the following:

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

I get the following:

```
INFO:  gem "bundler" is not installed
```

Any thoughts how can downgrade my bundler?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "gem list" output?

Comment: bundler (1.1.4)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.3) - All the default gems that came in with ruby installation

Comment: try "gem install bundler -v 1.0.15"

Comment: It is indeed.  Even trying force the bundler to use a specific version (bundle _1.0.15_ version) gives an error: `raise_if_conflicts': can't activate bundler-1.0.15, already activated bundler-1.1.4

Comment: Maybe "gem update bundler -v 1.0.15" ?

Comment: Just did. bundler (1.1.4, 1.0.15)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.3)... Version 1.1.4 still reigns supreme

Comment: Updating doesn't work either... gives "Nothing to update"

Comment: What about "gem uninstall bundler -v=1.1.4" now?

Comment: Same as per gem uninstall bundler. Gives "gem "bundler" is not installed"...

Comment: Maybe this http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=47956 helps you

Comment: See I'v wrote the possible soluteon below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution.

Apparently rvm installs it's gems in the global gemspec which is visible to all gemspecs.

So by doing:

```
rvm use 1.9.2@global
```

And followed by:

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

Does the trick.

This can be also shortened to:

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add the following to .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Or try to link the bundle to RVM bin dir

```
ln -s ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fonista/bin/bundle ~/.rvm/bin/
```